# поменять месторасположения

Tags: битрикс

Как можно реализовать месторасположение Страна - Область - Город. то есть без районов, подрайонов и тд. И строку города с подсказками[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В административном разделе перейдите `Магазин`-`Настройки`-`Свойства заказа`-`Список свойств` и отключите использование свойства отвечающего за область.